# how check if std::map key exists for object's property update otherwise insert a new one?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

in java, I sometimes do this

```
Map<String, POJO> objmap = new HashMap<String, POJO>();
POJO obj = null;
if ((obj = objMap.get(key)) == null) {
    obj = new POJO();
    objMap.put(key, obj);
}
obj.setName("something");
obj.setAddress("yeah");
```

What is the best practice to do similar thing in c++ with std::map?
to create a obj in map if not exist, then update its properties?

Comment: You should consider telling what the C++ map contains. Objects? Or pointers to objects? Anyway, `map.find(key)` might help you.

Comment: You can find a specific existing key using `std::map::find()`

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
void insert_or_update(const K & k, const T & t, std::map<K, T> & m)
{
    auto p = m.insert(std::make_pair(k, t));
    if (!p.second) p.first->second = t;
}
```

Or:

```
    m[k] = t;
```

The latter requires `T` to be default-constructible and assignable.

In C++17 you can also say:

```
m.insert_or_assign(k, t);
```

This has fewer restrictions than the above construction and returns information on whether the insertion took place, as well as the iterator to the element.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the insert function, it returns an iterator and a boolean regarding whether a new object was inserted:
something like this:

```
typedef map<int,void*> M;
M m;
auto insertion = m.insert(M::value_type(0,nullptr));
if (insertion.second) {
insertion.first->second = new... (// allocate your item or whatever, this is the iterator to it)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write `objmap[key] = value`.

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/

Comment: Not a good Idea! - when using the operator [], the value should be default-constructible.

Answer (score 0):

```
 std::map<std::string, POJO> mapStr2Pojo;
 mapStr2Pojo["something"].setName("something");
 mapStr2Pojo["something"].setAddress("yeah");
```

std::map<>'s operation[] inserts the object if it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

the insertion operation checks whether each inserted element has a key equivalent to the one of an element already in the container, and if so, the element is not inserted, returning an iterator to this existing element

```
    if ( !myMap.insert( std::make_pair( key, value ) ).second ) 
    {
        //  Element already present...
    }
```

Comment: An answer is always stronger if you also explain the solution.

Comment: agree. added explanation